# Split a malformed json

Tags: java, json

Hi I have a string that pretend be a json, that looks like this

```
{{"value":1}{"value":2}{"value":3}}
```

I want to split each jsonObject but I don't know how do it, something like this:

```
{{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":3}}
```

Comment: That output still isn't valid JSON

Comment: Yeah, you probably want `[{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":3}]`

Comment: You could regex find all `{"value":\d+}` patterns

Comment: For the best answer, you're going to have to explain where you _get_ this string data. Because the best fix is "fix that, so it outputs valid JSON" instead of trying to fix bad JSON after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

```java
String str = "{{\"value\":1}{\"value\":2}{\"value\":3}}";
String json = '[' + str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).replaceAll("}\\{", "},{")+ ']';
```

This is not 100% sure of syntax, but I think the approach is correct.

---

A less efficient, but reasonable approach is to use regular expression:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\"(?<key>[^\"]+)\":(?<value>\\d+)}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder().append('[');
int start = 0;

while (matcher.find(start)) {
    if (start > 0)
        buf.append(',');

    String key = matcher.group("key");
    String value = matcher.group("value");
    buf.append("{\"").append(key).append("\":").append(value).append('}');
    start = matcher.end();
}

String json = buf.append(']').toString();
```

Comment: This will fail with keys/values containing `}{` (which to be fair seems really improbable)

Comment: No, if `key/value` will contain `}{`, they should be encapsulated, because in the input string this is a special symbol.

Comment: I mean in one of the strings, e.g. `{{"value":"}{"}}`. I assume this would trip your search/replace, wouldn't it?

Comment: It's not possible to predict requirements. In the case of a given input string, my approach will work. But you are right, this is definitely not a universal one.

Comment: Yeah sure, I just meant to warn of the edge case but I'm sure this answer should satisfy OP's need.